# Read json file value in Go

Tags: json, go

I have a config file. I want to get specific value from that file. Here is my code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Configuration struct {
    consumer_key   string
    consumer_secret   string
    access_token   string
    access_token_secret   string
    db_name   string
    db_user   string
    db_password   string
    secret_key   string
    fb_page   string
    fb_page_token   string
    domain   string
}

func main() {
    file, _ := os.Open("./config.json")
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    configuration := Configuration{}
    error_ := decoder.Decode(&configuration)
     fmt.Println(configuration.domain)
}
```

config.json

```
{
  "consumer_key": "",
  "consumer_secret": "",
  "access_token": "",
  "access_token_secret": "",
  "db_name": "",
  "db_user": "",
  "db_password": "",
  "secret_key": "",
  "fb_page": "",
  "fb_page_token": "",
  "domain": "localhost:8000"
}
```

But the problem is it always print empty line, not the value `localhost:8000` I am expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [export](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Exported_identifiers) Configuration.domain field so that json package can see it.

Rename the domain field to Domain:

```
type Configuration struct {
  Domain string
}
```

You can also specify json name explicitly if it differs from field name:

```
type Configuration struct {
  Domain string `json:"domain_name"`
}
```